# Create html field with formatting buttons and store result in mySQL

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I am new to coding and I am trying to find a way to create an input field on a web page that has formatting buttons to enable e.g. bulleted lists, bold and underlined text etc. much like the text box that I am just using to post this question.

I already searched this site and googled but all I find is how to customize submit buttons or how to format input fields (like background color or general text appearance) but this is not what I am looking for.

I want to be able to create a custom formatted input like a bulleted list with some words that are bold or underlined and I want to store this formatted input in a mySQL database. If I then search the database and display the results on my page, I want the output to be formatted exactly as I submitted it.

So the questions are:

1. How do I create the input box with formatting buttons to customize my input? Is this possible with standard HTML? Do I need Javascript or PHP? If so, which functions and libraries to use?
2. How do I keep the formatting while storing the data in a database? I think I read elsewhere that storing HTML tags is not recommended?

Comment: You have 6 separate questions here. There should be one question per post. As for you programming problem, tackle one problem at a time. Get a page up, then start adding functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How do I create the input box with formatting buttons to customize my input? Is this possible with standard HTML? Do I need Javascript or PHP? If so, which functions and libraries to use?

You'd want to use a plugin. The plugin itself would most likely require minimal (if any) actual coding knowledge, and more likely just a copy+paste of relevant code from the plugin's instructions. Most plugins come with incredibly easy to follow startup guides.

Do a google search for "text editor plugins for website" and you'll get some solid results. The most common is probably [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/).

Regarding necessary technologies, PHP and JavaScript are not "one-or-the-other". JavaScript is a client-side language, meaning it manipulates the page in front of the user, not the actual data. For data manipulation, storage, retrieval, etc, you'd use a server-side programming language - like PHP. Of course, you can link these two technologies together to function as one, but that's not really in-line with what you're asking.

As you'd assume, storing this information obviously requires a database. Most databases are modified using some variation of SQL (though again, there are alternatives). Judging by your tags, it seems you're familiar with the idea of MySQL. Your PHP code would prepare the SQL and tell your MySQL database, "Here's some SQL - please execute it for me", and it would either go through successfully, or throw back an error for the PHP to interpret.

> How do I keep the formatting while storing the data in a database? I think I read elsewhere that storing HTML tags is not recommended?

For a basic starter site, storing HTML in a database is alright. As you get to bigger and bigger projects, you may want to consider a more adaptable solution so that your data isn't all hard-coded HTML, but for what it sounds like you're doing I don't think you'll have to worry.

A text string with some simple bold and italic tags is completely acceptable - it's only when you start to store entire elements or sections that you'd want to start considering other options.

Comment: I tried your suggestion and used the CDN version of CKEditor. It was very easy to setup and I stored the formatted output successfully in mySQL as a BLOB. Thank you for the help!

Comment: Glad to hear it! Remember to mark the answer as "accepted" if you found it a correct, sufficient, and complete response to your question!